# How to find a multi bracketed content using regex?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I want to find a bracketed formate like below.

It needs started with "**{id:**" ,and end with "**},**"
And the id value is A-Z. That's all.

I'm so confused by the inner brackets...

Below is a sample formate.

```
 {
            id: "A",
            cid: "6331411109881515776",
            latlng: {
                lat: 37.492488999999999,
                lng: 127.014357
            },
            image: "http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/ko_kr/mapfiles/markers2/markerA.png",
            sprite: {
                width: 20,
                height: 34,
                top: 0,
                image: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_markers_A_J2.png"
            },
            icon_id: "A",
            drg: true,
            laddr: "강남대성학원, 서울특별시 서초구 서초1동 1657-7",
            geocode: "CQISkUJWkUyzFQkXPAId1RWSByEAD3Pz27DdVym31_joa6F8NTEAD3Pz27DdVw",
            sxti: "강남대성학원",
            sxst: "서초1동",
            sxsn: "1657-7",
            sxct: "서울특별시",
            sxpr: "",
            sxpo: "137-071",
            sxcn: "KR",
            sxph: "+8225817217",
            name: "강남대성학원",
            ss: {
                edit: true,
                detailseditable: true,
                deleted: false,
                rapenabled: true,
                mmenabled: true
            },
            elms: [
                4,
                1,
                6,
                1,
                10,
                2,
                12,
                1,
                9,
                1,
                5,
                2,
                11
            ]
        },
```

Thanks for your help~~

****** edited 2012/07/19 *************

My code is

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.co.kr?q=%@&output=json", 
                       [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//#define NSKoreanEncoding  0x80000422
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSKoreanEncoding];

//remove the while(1); from data
dataString = [dataString substringFromIndex:9];

// Create SBJSON object to parse JSON
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:dataString error:&error];

NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);
NSLog(@"dataString: %@",dataString);

//Samples can get result
NSString *jsonStr  = @"{\"name\":\"jia\",\"age\":\"24\"}";  
NSString *jsonStr2 = @"[\"1\",\"2\"]";  

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];  

dict = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonStr];  
NSLog(@"%@",dict);  

NSMutableArray *arr = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonStr2];  
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Because the true JSON object is a "key" = "value" formate, I can't use them to dictionary...
Besides, there is a way to change the formate...

Below is several lines of Java code that the same as my target.

```
//remove while(1);
String jsonString = sb.toString().substring(9);

Log.d(TAG_SERVER, jsonString);
JSONObject jj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
//get "overlays" object
JSONObject overlays = jj.getJSONObject("overlays");
//get "markers" object
JSONArray markers = overlays.getJSONArray("markers");
```

My goal is to get the markers.
They contains a full search result of google map.

If someone knows how to do it, please tell me~~

Comment: Can you give a small sample of what should be returned according to your code.

Comment: @Burnzy I edited it~~ thanks~~

Answer (score 3):

Regex can't match nested structures by itself, and recursive regex is a mess.

The best thing you could do is to use a proper JSON-parser. There are many libraries to choose from. See the bottom of  http://json.org/ for a list of a few.

---

**Example:** (using [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON))

```
NSData *theJSONData = /* load your JSON data */

// Look for the opening '{'
const unsigned char *buf = [theJSONData bytes];
NSUInteger len = [theJSONData length];
if (len > 32) len = 32;
NSUInteger start;
for (start = 0; start < len; start++) {
    if (buf[start] == '{') break;
}
if (start == len) {
    NSLog(@"Could not find '{'");
}

// Cut off any prefix javascript ("while(1);")
if (start > 0) {
    len = [theJSONData length];
    theJSONData = [theJSONData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(start,len-start)];
}

NSError *theError = nil;
NSDictionary *theObject = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer]
        deserializeAsDictionary:theJSONData
        error:&theError];

// Print the cid
NSLog(@"cid = %@", [theObject objectForKey:@"cid"]);
```

**Output:**

```
cid = 6331411109881515776
```

Comment: I gave +1 even though, IMHO, this is a simple enough case(counting brackets) where Regex + stack/recursion could cleanly solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, but there are a lot corner-cases, and it would make a lot of code. There already are several libraries that can parse it.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `NSJSONSerialization` API?

Comment: @omz I didn't know about it. I picked the first one I found.

Comment: @omz Thanks for your advise.But it not works...JSON Object needs "key" = "value" format.When using the TouchJSON, it results a error `ERROR: Error Domain=kJSONScannerErrorDomain Code=-102 "Could not scan dictionary. Failed to scan a key." UserInfo=0x796d350 {snippet=!HERE>!{name:"jia",age:"24", location=0, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not scan dictionary. Failed to scan a key., character=0, line=0} ` ...  But in Java, just use JSONObject can get the dictionary... Is there any way to let the JSON support key = "value" formate?? If not, I think I had to use NSPredicate to solve this problem...

Comment: @8bitwide yah,that's a simple way. But my string is very big... [file](http://maps.google.com?q=%chicago&output=json) I want to dictionary this file to get the full search results in iOS.

Comment: @StevenJiang The file contains some execution-protection. You have to cut off the prefix javascript code, up until the first `{`. See my updated code.

Comment: Thx for your help.I used these lines to get the data on your coed.`NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com?q=%@&output=json", [@"chicago" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData *theJSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:kNilOptions error:&error];`

Comment: But,It returns a error `Error Domain=kJSONScannerErrorDomain Code=-12 "Could not scan data. Data wasn't encoded properly?" UserInfo=0x6e4c200 {snippet=!HERE>!, location=0, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not scan data. Data wasn't encoded properly?, character=0, line=0}
` when calling the `deserializeAsDictionary` code...

Comment: The error-message is not from TouchJSON. There might be some encoding problems.

Comment: I fixed the encoding error, but it comes to `Error Domain=kJSONScannerErrorDomain Code=-102 "Could not scan dictionary. Failed to scan a key." UserInfo=0x6e89ee0 {snippet=!HERE>!{title:"chicago - Go, location=0, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not scan dictionary. Failed to scan a key., character=0, line=0}` again...

Comment: TouchJSON does not seem to allow unquoted dictionary keys. Instead of using `search?output=json`, you should try the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). It uses proper JSON formatting. Example: [maps.googleapis.com/.../json?address=chicago&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=chicago&sensor=false)

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Yes,I tried it.But it is searching by the address name.I want a result the same as searching on google map shows.I think I had to using the RegEx to fetching the infos...Thanks anyway~~